# Does microsoft pubseekoff have a bug?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Consider code below (Visual Studio 2015/2017)

```
std::wostringstream stm;
stm << L"12345";
std::wcout << stm.rdbuf()->pubseekoff(std::ios_base::cur, 0, std::ios_base::out) << L"\n"
stm << L"67890";
std::wcout << stm.str();
```

I see

```
1
167890
```

But I expect to see

```
5
1234567890
```

Is this microsoft bug or I something don't understand?

Comment: `streampos pubseekoff (streamoff off, ios_base::seekdir way, ios_base::openmode which = ...)` -- don't you have arguments `off` and `way` given in the wrong order?

Comment: @CygnusX1, yes! Thank you!

Comment: I would blame the weak type system. `ios_base::seekdir` and `streamoff` should really be different, unrelated types. Type systems are designed to catch exactly that kind of errors!

Comment: @CygnusX1 I completely agree with you. Do you mind if I remove this post at all?

Comment: Note that with GDBs' library, it won't build `error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘std::ios_base::seekdir {aka std::_Ios_Seekdir}’ [-fpermissive]`